# bigquery query exceeds memory limits, how to refactor?

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a query where I am trying to get a count of items in table2 using table1.  The following is a simplication of it.  It worked fine most of the time, but then, there are some days where the data is structured in such a way where this sql code starts to cause over memory limit errors.  I've been trying to debug it with the query planner.  It says that it is running out of resources in the aggregate stage, but looking at the planner info, I still cannot understand why it is running out of memory.  Can this query be re-written in another way that will make it use less memory?  Here is the query planner failing stage image [image]

```
-- create table
create table actions1(
    start_date datetime --goes back 1 year
    , end_date datetime
    , action varchar(200)
    , idA int64
    , idB int64
);

create table actions2(
    action2_date datetime
    , action varchar(300)
    , idA int64
    , idB int64
);

-- the query

WITH filter_actions_helper AS (
    SELECT 
        a1.action, a1.start_date, a2.start_date
        , ARRAY_AGG(action2_date IGNORE NULL) action2col
    FROM 
        actions1 a1
    LEFT JOIN 
        actions2 a2 
        using(idA, idB)
    GROUP BY 
        idA, idB
)
, filter_actions AS (
    SELECT 
        idA, idB, start_date, end_date
        , sum( if(exists( SELECT * FROM UNNEST(action2col) a WHERE a >= start_date), 1,0) ) engaged
    FROM 
        filter_actions_helper f
    GROUP BY
        idA, idB
)
select * from filter_actions;
```

Comment: How big are the arrays that are being created? Can you temporarily replace the `ARRAY_AGG` with a `COUNT(*)` to check?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that in the case of my query, I can break the large aggregation into views (CTE), calculate each individual aggregation and then join everything back together.  Secondly, using COUNTIF also works, though there is no noticeable performance difference.